# Aggregation and grouped index with pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
User ID Year    Amount
A       2009    5
A       2010    6
A       2009    6
A       2010    1
B       2010    1
B       2009    1
B       2010    2
B       2010    5
```

And I want to sum of the user's amount for each year.. And want to result like this:

```
    Sum of amount   
User    2009    2010

  A        11   7
  B        1    8
```

I can handle this for only a year. Like this:

```
newdf= df.groupby('User ID')['Amount'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: It results some kind different....

Comment: I want to give top label "Sum of amount" that covers years

Comment: Sorry, I add answer.

Comment: Sorry for late, I wasn't on the pc

Comment: Glad can help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rename` for new level of `MultiIndex`, then add column `Year` to `groupby` and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html). Last for remove column names add [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
newdf = (df.rename(columns={'Amount':'Sum of amount'})
         .groupby(['User ID', 'Year'])
         .sum()
         .unstack()
         .rename_axis((None, None), axis=1))
print (newdf)

        Sum of amount     
                 2009 2010
User ID                   
A                  11    7
B                   1    8
```

But if not necessary rename column, solution is simplify:

```
newdf= df.groupby(['User ID', 'Year']).sum().unstack()
print (newdf)
        Amount     
Year      2009 2010
User ID            
A           11    7
B            1    8
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `pivot_table`

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index=['UserID'],columns=['Year'],values=['Amount'],aggfunc='sum')
Out[906]: 
       Amount     
Year     2009 2010
UserID            
A          11    7
B           1    8
```